# SQL Group by range and total column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

With the following function and stored procedure i get a resultset with 2 columns.
What i need additional is a third column total for all open invoices inner score range
It would great for any idea.

```
  ALTER FUNCTION dbo.OpenOrders
    (
    @MandantId int
    )
  RETURNS TABLE
  AS
  RETURN
  SELECT        SUM(Invoices.Amount - ISNULL(Payment.Amount, 0)) AS Op
  FROM            Invoices INNER JOIN
                           Orders ON Invoices.OrderId = Orders.OrderId LEFT  OUTER JOIN
                           Payment ON Invoices.InvoiceId = Payment.InvoiceId
  WHERE        (Orders.MandantId = @MandantId)
  GROUP BY Invoice.InvoiceId, Invoices.Amount
  HAVING        (SUM(Invoices.Amount - ISNULL(Payment.Amount, 0)) <> 0)


  ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.GetOpRanges
  @MandantId int
  AS
  BEGIN

    SELECT * INTO #tmp_ranges

    FROM

    //wrong in first post -> OPDebitorByMandant(@MandantId)
    OpenOrders(@MandantId)

    SELECT  op AS [score range], COUNT(*) AS [number of occurences]
    FROM
    (SELECT CASE
      WHEN op BETWEEN 0 AND 50 THEN '  0- 50'
      WHEN op BETWEEN 50 AND 100 THEN ' 50-100' 
      WHEN op BETWEEN 100 AND 500 THEN '100-500' 
      ELSE '500 and >' END AS op
    FROM [#tmp_ranges]) AS t

    GROUP BY op

    RETURN

Result:
score range number of occurences range
------------------+-------------
  0- 50            23
 50-100            4
100-500            4
500 and >          21

What i need additional is a third column total for all open invoices inner score range.

Target result:
score range number of occurences Total
-----------+--------------------+------
  0- 50            23             1.150
 50-100            4                400
100-500            4              2.000
500 and >          21            22.000

      Tables:                                                                                                                                                                                 
    Invoices 
    InvoiceId  CustomerId OrderId DateOfInvoice Amount
    ----------+----------+-------+-------------+------
    1          1           20      20160301      1000.00
    2          2           22      20160501      2000.00
    3          1          102      20160601      3000.00
    ...

    Orders
    OrderId MandantId CustomerId DateOfOrder Amount
    -------+---------+----------+-----------+-----------
     20     1         1          20160101     1000.00
     22     1         2          20160101     2000.00
    102     1         1          20160101     3000.00
    ...

    Payment
    PaymentId MandantId CustomerId InvoiceId OrderId DateOfPayment Amount 
    ---------+---------+----------+---------+-------+-------------+-------------
    1         1         1          1          20     20160310      1000.00
    2         1         2          2          22     20160505      2000.00
    3         1         1          3         102     20160610      3000.00
    ...
```

hope it's helpfull and thanks again in advance for any solution

Comment: How to find open invoices. Also add sample data of `Invoices`, `Orders` and `Payment` tables.

Comment: Logic inside function also looks bit off

Comment: How do you expect to get the data of `Third column - Total`?

Comment: as @Prdp said how do you expect got good answer when you did not decsribe your main tables?

Comment: I hope now it`s more understandable what i need.@Prdp